# haskell add item to list not working

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to add a string to a list of strings using the `:` operator, but somehow it's not working properly... This code is working:

```
sl:(printH header):sl:(map printR t)
```

but when I try to add the string `sl` on the end as well, like this:

```
sl:(printH header):sl:(map printR t):sl
```

it throws out an error, which doesn't make any sense to me (sincwe the other joins did go well):

```
Couldn't match type '[Char]' with 'Char'
Expected type: [String] -> Char
  Actual type: [String] -> String
In the first argument of 'map', namely 'printR'
...
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Prelude> :type (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

This tells you that the `(:)` function takes a single item on the left and a list on the right. Given:

```
a :: t
b :: t
c :: [t],
```

`a:b:c` parses as `a:(b:c)`, which works, because the expression `b:c` is of type `[t]`. Meanwhile, `b:c:a` parses as `b:(c:a)`, which doesn't work, because `c:a` is ill-typed: `a` should be of type `[t]`, but is actually of type `t`, and `c` should be of type `t`, but is actually of type `[t]`. In your example, `t` is `Char`.

If you want to add a single item to the end of a list, you can use concatenate `(++)`:

`xs ++ [i]`

Answer (score 3):

Operator `:` is used to **prepend** an element to a list.  In your expression

```
sl:(printH header):sl:(map printR t)
```

the first three expressions (`sl`, `printH header` and `sl`) are list elements (strings, apparently), whereas the fourth one (`map printR t`) is the list to prepend those to.

If you want to **append** an element to the list, you cannot use operator `:`.  You will have to use something like:

```
sl:(printH header):sl:(map printR t) ++ [sl]
```